# Python: как преобразовать строки при импорте из файла?

Tags: python, файлы

Есть текстовый файл, в котором данные хранятся в виде матрицы:

```
0 1
1 0
```

Формат именно такой, увеличить кол-во строчек по одному значению в каждой нельзя.

Я делаю импорт из этого файла в список:

```
def initPoints():
    points = []
    f = open('scores.txt')
    points = f.read().splitlines()
    f.close()
    print(points)

initPoints()
```

Результат:

```
['0 1', '1 0']
```

Мне же нужно, чтобы результат принял такой вид:

```
['0', '1', '1', '0']
```

Пока не могу понять, как сделать. Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

Comment: @pikey ого какой хост для картинок. Привет от латышского подполья.

Comment: Говорят, йован похитил разум биологов, юзернейм ;)

Answer (score 6):

```
points = f.read().split()
```

Comment: Интерпретатор видит какие-то символы форматирования в начале первой строки. Вот что на выходе получается:

    ['п»ї0', '1', '1', '0']

Хотя в исходном scores.txt нет ничего, что намекало бы на формат. Что это может быть?

Comment: f.read().strip().split()

Comment: @pikey utf-BOM, например. Думаю, что нужно дулать codecs.open(file, 'r', 'utf-8-sig')

Comment: А если исходный файл не в utf-8? Я ведь верно понял - 'utf-8-sig' говорит интерпретатору читать файл как utf-8?

Comment: @pikey, да, но цифры, насколько понимаю, кодируются одинаково вне зависимости от кодировки. Тут проблема может быть только если питон не найдет эти первые три байта. Но если файл создается и обрабатывается исключительно программой, то там внезапностей быть не должно.

Comment: Да, спасибо, *import codecs* решило проболему. Читает при любой кодировке файла.

Answer (score 1):

Я тут, с вашей помощью, допилил то, что нужно было допилить. В принципе, всё работает, как тебуется. Единственное, что хотелось бы прояснить для себя  - как добиться того же результата, но с более компактным кодом?

Например, вот одна функция:

```
def newScores():
    global result
    global scores
    result = int(input("Enter 1, if the computer won, or enter '0' otherwise: "))
    if (result==1):
        print ("PC's won this round, total score list has been adjusted:")
        scores[0] = (scores[0]+1)
        scores[3] = (scores[3]+1)
    else:
        print ("You've won this round, total score list has been adjusted:")
        scores[1] = (scores[1]+1)
        scores[2] = (scores[2]+1)
    print (scores)
newScores()
```

- как написать операции по изменению значений строк в списке поболеелучшей?

И вот:

```
def updateScores():
    global scores
    scores = [str(x) for x in scores]
    print ("")
    # the next 2 lines is there for testing, should be removed later on
    print ("The 'scorelist' has been converted to strings:")
    print (scores)
    scores[0] = (scores[0]+" "+scores[1]+"\n")
    scores[1] = (scores[2]+" "+scores[3])
    scores.remove(scores[2])
    scores.remove(scores[2])
    print (scores)
    f = open("scoretest.txt", "w+")
    line = f.writelines(scores)
    f.close()
updateScores()
```

Как все эти операции со строками написать в более сжатом виде?

Comment: @pikey, 

> Как все эти операции со строками написать в более сжатом виде?

Питон очень хорош в форматировании строк:

    >>> scores_string = '%d %d\n%d %d' % (1, 3, 5, 19)
    >>> print scores_string
    1 3
    5 19

И в нарезке строк и массивов (операция называется slice)

    >>> [1,2,3,4][:2] # взять два первых элемента
    [1, 2]

Как выше писал, для открытия файлов существует очень удобная конструкция with:

    with open('scoretest.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(score_string)